Mind the gap between……
I am new to creating puzzles, and this is the first puzzle I've designed for PSE!

After completing these mini crosswords, you can extract a word from them.The answer consists of a five-letter word.
hint:

 The word "Gap" has a five-letter synonym, which is the key to this puzzle.


Here are the solved crosswords:

 

As for the metapuzzle (thanks @F1Krazy and @MOehm):

 We can draw lines on the crosswords where the spaces occur (including in between abbreviation letters):


 

forming the word:

 GRAZE!


The crossword is correct（except for Down 1 in the first mini crossword）! But regarding the second step, I must say that the letters themselves are useless; you might need to pay more attention to... some other gaps in the crossword you ignored!

Based on the hint, I tried (rot13) qenjvat yvarf ba gur pebffjbeq pbeerfcbaqvat gb jurer gur fcnprf (tncf) jbhyq or va gur jbeqf. Gur yvarf sbez gur yrggref "TEUFR", juvpu V pna'g znxr urnq abe gnvy bs. I feel like I'm the right track though...

@F1Krazy That has to be it in some way, yeah. rot13: Gur sbhegu tevq pbhyq or n "m" vafgrnq bs na "f", ohg gung qbrfa'g uryc.

You're very close: I think you should treat the fisrt parts of two down clues in grid 3 like clue 2 in the first grid.

@MOehm Aha, you've got it- thanks!

Good play, well done!
